# How to load image in knockout js?

Tags: knockout.js

I am using html binding like below

```
< img data-bind="attr: { href: movieUrl }"  width="200" height="300"/>
```

and in KO view model I am using like below

```
this.movieUrl = ko.observable("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRd7Cufx4u8LrlQ2TBSRxtl6RPG6XizocBD64YibmE1Gv8hw2O6");
```

Here image is not fetching from both local drive and web url.Here i am giving correct url. Please help me how to load image in KO.

Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set not `href` attribute to show image, but `src`. Change your code like this:

```
<img data-bind="attr: { src: movieUrl }"  width="200" height="300"/>
```